# How to build a C# application and installer that uses SQL Server LocalDB to be accesible to all users on same PC without prompt by UAC?

Tags: sql-server, uac, localdb

My app runs normally under Windows Administrator account there is no problem.

Except that when run under Guest Account, it has to be run as administrator for the DB to be accessible, or else I'll get an error

> Failed to update .mdf database because the database is read-only

So UAC always pops up if Guest account wants the app to work.

The purpose of the app is for everyone, but whenever a guest user runs it, an admin has to run over and enter his password into UAC -- that is going to wear out the patience of everyone, don't you think? What I need (and in my opinion, logical) is for it to run as admin automatically once installed (admin installs it anyway). Or at least, an admin need enter password on UAC only once, not every time.

Is this really not easily available?

Comment: localDB is [meant to be a development tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15), not for live use. It's just so you can test a database easily while creating your app. For real use, Microsoft intends you to install a real SQL Server instance. That might be overkill for a one-machine app, so maybe consider using a different database e.g. SqlLite - which is file-based and doesn't require any installation at all. Or possibly you could use regular SQL Server Express (but not in localdb mode).

Comment: Use SQL Server Express instead.

Comment: As mentioned in comments above, after deploy your database in sql express (in the same machine that you sayd), create a sql server user with and Grant operations; and add the connection string into your Application app.config with the data connections (obviously include this new user and password).

Answer (score 0):

Set the permissions on the database files:

- MyDatabase.mdf
- MyDatabase_log.ldf

So that <kbd>Everyone</kbd> has **Full Control**.